# Pause between images in Java

Tags: java, swing, imageicon

I've created a GUI that goes to a new screen (JPanel) when a button is clicked. After this, I would like it to show ImageIcons from an array (1 every few seconds), replacing the old one with the new one. I have seen ways to "pause" the execution for a specified amount of seconds (`Thread.sleep()`), but this only seems to pause the amount of time between the button being clicked and going to the new screen, only displaying the last image.

I've tried this:

```
    for(int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++) {
        try{
            Thread.sleep(1000);
            g.drawImage(myImageArray[i]);
        } catch(Exception e) {
           System.out.println("Exception caught");
        }
    }
```

With no luck. Any suggestions?

Comment: That's because you are doing all processing in the same thread. You should do all processing in a separate thread and GUI updates in a separate thread (called Event Dispatching Thread). Take a look at [Swing Concurrency](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/)

Comment: See [Concurrency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/) and use a Swing `Timer` instead, [How to use Swing Timers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html), for [example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24111940/how-to-update-a-jframe-in-a-second-window/24112256#24112256)

Comment: Look at Mad's answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13870982/updating-swing-components-correctly) and also [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13870982/updating-swing-components-correctly).

Comment: MadProgrammer is right. Use Timers instead of sleeping the thread.

Comment: I can't figure out how to use the actionPerformed method, do I have to loop inside of the method or before or after? `Timer tm = new Timer(500,new ActionListener() {

             @Override
             public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                  for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
                   g.drawImage(photos[i].getImage(),(900/2)-(photos[i].getIconWidth()/2), 
                 (600/2)-(photos[i].getIconHeight()/2), photos[i].getIconWidth(), photos[i].getIconHeight(), null);
                  }
             }
         });
         ;
      
         tm.start();`